# Prevent inline div from wrapping whilst container is truncated

Tags: css, layout, sass, whitespace, word-wrap

I am trying to do something I'm fairly certain is impossible without some JS.

I have three variable-width items on the same line. The righthand item is always floated left - that's the easy part. The middle item needs to sit directly after the first item which needs to truncate (with an ellipsis) if it is too wide for the given space. The problem is that the middle item should not be truncated - if it reaches the end of the container, the first item should truncate against it.

There is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/VYXXWM) here showing two variations that each have properties that I need:

1. The middle item is inside the left item as an inline block. If the text of the left item increases, the middle item is pushed ahead of it. However this means the middle item is truncated if it reaches the edge of the right item.
2. The middle item is floated right, so that the left item truncates when it reaches it. However this means the middle item is always to the far right and doesn't sit right after the first item.

**Is there any way of reconciling these two requirements without resorting to JS?**

HTML

```
<div class="Wrapper -nested">
  <div class="Right">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="Left">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras tempus, risus ut porta venenatis, ipsum ante laoreet odio, id bibendum odio ante et arcu. Integer.
    <span class="Middle">MIDDLE</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper -floated">
  <div class="Right">RIGHT</div>
  <span class="Middle">MIDDLE</span>
  <div class="Left">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras tempus, risus ut porta venenatis, ipsum ante laoreet odio, id bibendum odio ante et arcu. Integer.
  </div>
</div>
```

Sass (scss)

```
.Left,
.Middle,
.Right {
  padding: 5px;
}

.Left {
  background: desaturate(red, 50);
}

.Middle {
  background: red;
}

.Right {
  background: desaturate(red, 80);;
}

.Wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  &.-floated {

    .Left {
      display:block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .Middle,
    .Right {
      float: right
    }
  }


  &.-nested {

    .Left {
      display:block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .Middle {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .Right {
      float: right
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would `display:flex;` be an option for you ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNvjNj
 (same as snippet below)

```css
.Left,
.Middle,
.Right {
  padding: 5px;
}

.Left {
  order:1;
  flex:1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.Middle {
order:2;

}

.Right {
  order:3;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.Wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display:flex;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Right">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="Middle">MIDDLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</div>
  <div class="Left">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras tempus, risus ut porta venenatis, ipsum ante laoreet odio, id bibendum odio ante et arcu. Integer.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this any different from 'Wrapper -floated'?